# How can I pass a vector as an argument to another vector?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I am having trouble passing a vector of object to another vector of objects of different type. What I am trying to do is make an object Partidas that displays an array or vector of objects of type Producto, along with some other attributes but those are ints and string and I have no problem with those. When I run my program, when done going through my las loop by pressing '0' it marks BAD ACCESS. I know the code is a little long but I tried to put everything in the question so hopefully you guys can help me out. Also, if you know a better way to do what I'm trying to do please let me know so. Thanks!

---

```
vector<Producto> vectorProductos;

while(file >> sID >> sDesc >> sUMed >> sFam >> sClass >> dVolumen >> dLongitud >> sPrecio){
vectorProductos.push_back(Producto(sID, sDesc, sUMed, sFam, sClass, dVolumen, dLongitud, stringToDouble(sPrecio)));
iNumProductos++;
}
file.close();


char cOption;
int iNumPartidas;
do{
    cout << "Menu." << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "a. Crear un proyecto." << endl;
    cout << "b. Ver lista de proyectos." << endl;
    cout << "c. Ver lista de productos existentes." << endl;

    cout << "z. Terminar programa." << endl;
    cin >> cOption;
    switch(cOption){
        case 'a':

        cout << "Nombre de proyecto:\t";
        cin >> sTitulo;
        cout << "Numero de partidas de proyecto " << sTitulo << ":\t";
        cin >> iNumPartidas;
        cout << "Descripcion:\t";
        cin >> sDescProyecto;
        for(unsigned int iP = 1; iP <= iNumPartidas; iP++){ 
            string sDescPart;
            vector<Producto> vecProdxP;
            vector<Partida> vectorPartidas;
            cout << endl << "Partida " << iP << ":" << endl;
            cout << "Clave de partida:\t";
            cin >> sPartida;
            cout << "Descripcion de Partida:\t";
            cin >> sDescPart;

            for(unsigned int iPrd = 0; iPrd < iNumProductos; iPrd++){
                cout << endl << "Clave de producto " << iPrd+1 << ":\t";
                cin >> sClave;
            if(sClave != "0"){
                for(int iC = 0; iC < vectorProductos.size(); iC++){
                    //  int index = 0;
                    if(sClave == vectorProductos[iC].getClave()){
                        cout << "Cantidad:\t";
                        cin >> iCantProdxP;
                        file.open("/Users/javiersantisteban/Documents/Prueba/Prueba/ListaDePrecios.txt");
                        while(file >> sID >> sDesc >> sUMed >> sFam >> sClass >> dVolumen >> dLongitud >> sPrecio){
                if(sID == sClave){
                    vecProdxP.push_back(Producto(sID, sDesc, sUMed, sFam, sClass, dVolumen, dLongitud, stringToDouble(sPrecio)));
                                 }
                        }
                        file.close();

                    }
                }
                }else{
                iPrd = iNumProductos;
                }

            }
            vectorPartidas.push_back(Partida(sPartida, sDescPart, vecProdxP));
        }
```

---

Class Partida

```
#ifndef Partidas_h
#define Partidas_h

#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>
#include "Producto.h"

using namespace std;

class Partida{
private:
    string _sPartida, _sDescripcion;//double _dPrecioPartida;
    vector<Producto> _vecProd;

public:
    Partida();
    Partida(string, string, vector<Producto>);
    inline string getClave(){return _sPartida;}
    inline string getProy(){return _sDescripcion;}
    inline void setClave(string sPartida){_sPartida = sPartida;}
    inline void setProy(string sDescripcion){_sDescripcion = sDescripcion;}
    void toString();
};
Partida::Partida(){
_sPartida = "";
_sDescripcion = "";
}
Partida::Partida(string sPartida, string sTitulo, vector<Producto> vecProd){
_sPartida = sPartida;
_sDescripcion = sTitulo;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecProd.size(); i++){
    _vecProd[i] = vecProd[i];
}
}
void Partida::toString(){
cout << "Clave de Partida:\t" << _sPartida << endl;
cout << "Proyecto:\t" << _sDescripcion << endl;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _vecProd.size();i++){
    _vecProd[i].toString();
    cout << endl;
}

}

#endif /* Partida_h */
```

Comment: You kind of forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense -- vectors are not functions, so don't take arguments.  What do mean by 'pass an argument to a vector'?

Comment: you need to create a [MCVE]. How are all the `cout`s relevant to the problem? How is the menu selection relevant to the problem? How is the file opening relevant to the problem? How are all the methods in `Partida` relevant to the problem? And oh yes, as  Lightness Races in Orbit said what is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @ChrisDodd The class Partidas has as an attribute a vector of type Producto, what I need is to display a vector of Productos when the user wants to see the "Productos (Products)" that a "Partida" has. Sorry if I miswrote.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having trouble passing a vector of object to another vector of objects of different type.

That doesn't really make any sense. What would a vector of objects of one type do with a vector of objects of a different type?

> What I am trying to do is make an object Partidas that displays an array or vector of objects of type Producto, along with some other attributes but those are ints and string and I have no problem with those.

Okay, so you want an object that performs some operations on a vector of objects of another type. That seems reasonable.

> I know the code is a little long but I tried to put everything in the question so hopefully you guys can help me out. Also, if you know a better way to do what I'm trying to do please let me know so. It is my first job as a programmer and I want a good start. Thanks!

You didn't tell us what problem you're having. Is the code not compiling? Crashing? Working but not doing what you want? It's hard to help without knowing what's wrong. But here's a stab in the dark:

```
Partida::Partida(string sPartida, string sTitulo, vector<Producto> vecProd){
_sPartida = sPartida;
_sDescripcion = sTitulo;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecProd.size(); i++){
    _vecProd[i] = vecProd[i];
}
}
```

This code assigns values to objects that don't exist. Since `_vecProd` is an empty vector, there is no `_vecProd[0]` to assign a value to in the loop. I'm not sure why you go through contortions just to initialize objects to particular values -- C++ has a simple object initialization syntax using [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).